# Is there a command which will print the path of the file in the repo-browser in the command line

Tags: svn, file, command-line, command, path

Dupe of [Is there a command which will print the path of the file in the repo-browser in the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048356/is-there-a-command-which-will-print-the-path-of-the-file-in-the-repo-browser-in-t)

Is there a command which will print the path of the file in the repo-browser in the command line?

SVN diff only prints the file name.

Thank you.

Comment: I find your question hard to understand. Perhaps you could give an example of the kind of thing you're looking for - what would the ideal command (and output) look like?

Comment: You shouldn't ask the same question twice. Be patient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `svn info <file>` to get details about the file. This includes the URL, which in case of a file includes its path in the repository. If you need only the path without the repository root you get the repository root in the output too so can easily filter it.